# Get data from an array to create dynamically <Text> component react-native

Tags: arrays, react-native

I got array:

```
const DATA_Section = [
  {
    id: 0,
    text: "Some text1",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Some text2",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Some text 3",
  },
];
```

and I want to use text from this array to create dynamic  component. Idea is: I can see text[0], I click some button then I can see text[1], something like loop. How can to do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Could you share that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way maybe.

```
const DATA_Section = [
  {
    id: 0,
    text: "Some text1",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Some text2",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Some text 3",
  },
];

const Component: FC = () => {
  const [initialRenderState, setInitialRenderState] = 
  useState(DATA_Section[0])

  return (
    <View>
      {intialRenderState.map(item => <Text key={item.id}>{item.text}</Text>)}
      <Pressable onPress={()=> setInitialRenderState(prevState => [...prevState, Data_Section[prevState.length]])}>
        <Text>Add item</Text>
      <Pressable>
    </View>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const DATA_Section = [
{
  id: 0,
  text: "Some text1",
},
{
  id: 1,
  text: "Some text2",
},
{
  id: 2,
  text: "Some text 3",
},
];

const sample = () => {

  const [ index, setIndex ] = useState(0);

  const handleChangeIndex = () => {
  if (index < DATA_Section.length) {
  setIndex(index + 1);
  }else{
  setIndex(0);
  }
  }
return(
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>handleChangeIndex()}>
<View style={{width:100, height:50, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
<Text>
{DATA_Section[index].text}
</Text>
</View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</View>
);

}
```